# The resource cannot be found after refresh

Tags: asp.net

Dears ,

Below code in Ctrl_Menu.ascx is navigating to Accounts page

```
<li class="">
                    <a href="../EmployeeSchedule/Administration/Account/AccountsView.aspx" title="Bootstrap Tables">
                      <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"><span class="overlay-label greensea80"></span></i>
                     Accounts
                    </a>
                  </li>
```

It works fine , but while im in accountsView.aspx , if I press again on it , it will show that source cannopt be found.
Error:Requested URL:/EmployeeSchedule/Administration/EmployeeSchedule/Administration/Account/AccountsView.aspx

I have no idea why it duplicate this “EmployeeSchedule/Administration ”

To be more clear , Here’s the code for Ctrl_Menu.ascx whih is registered in ctrl_Header.ascx and ctrl_Header.ascx is registered in the master page.

```
<%@Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ctrl_Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="ctrl_header" %>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" id="navigation">

              <li class="collapsed-content">
                <!-- Collapsed content pasting here at 768px -->
              </li>
              <li class="user-status status-online hide" id="user-status">
               <div class="profile-photo">
                 // <img src="images/profile-photo.jpg" alt= /> 
                </div>
                <div class="user">
                  mnhgcjhgcjhgfjhgf <strong>jhgfjhgf</strong>
                  <span class="role">Administrator</span>

                </div>
              </li>
     <li class="">
                    <a href="../EmployeeSchedule/Administration/Account/AccountsView.aspx" title="Bootstrap Tables">
                      <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"><span class="overlay-label greensea80"></span></i>
                     Accounts
                    </a>
                  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Guys, you can ask more question or if I can make it more clear, please reply me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/EmployeeSchedule/Administration/Account/AccountsView.aspx") %>"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kailash